# Solve $z''+z=x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Considering the ansats $z=ax+b$. If I'm missing one degree in the LHS in the differential equation, shouln't I multiply my ansatz by $x$ and get the ansatz and instead get $ax^2+bx$? If not, when does this apply?

Comment: The homogeneous has roots $\pm~i$. If the RHS had had a $\cos x$ and/or $\sin x$ term, then you would have had to use $z_p = x(a \cos x + b \sin x)$. As it stands, you did fine.

Comment: in this case solution is $z=c_1 \cos x+ c_2 \sin x+x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $z$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, then also $z''+z$ is.

Since you want that $z''+z$ has degree $1$, also $z$ should have degree $1$.

Thus $z=ax+b$ and so $z''=0$, which yields $a=1$ and $b=0$.

Answer (score 0):

***Hint***
$$z"+z=x$$

$$(z-x)'' +(z-x)=0$$
Substitute $f=z-x$
$$f'' +f=0$$

$$r^2+1=0$$
$r=\pm i$
$$f=c_1\cos(x)+c_2\sin(x)$$
$z=f+x$
$$z=c_1\cos(x)+c_2\sin(x)+x$$